# removing image in view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I seem to be having a problem removing the image in UIScrollView. I was able to remove it from `NSDocumentDirectory` but it still stays in the view. how to remove it when button is pressed too. Here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", button.tag]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to remove the view from the super view like the following

```
//In your button clicked function
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: Show us how do you add the image to the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

I think after finish your delete option. you doesn't reload your view. so that i remain that image.